# Custom built gcc 4.6.3 and gcc 5.4.0 include search list differs

Tags: gcc, ubuntu-16.04

I need to build some old gcc versions on Ubuntu 16. Primary goal is 4.6.3, but seems I have an include search list issue. 
Builds using this compiler fail because sys/cdefs.h cannot be found. I have checked the include search paths for the compiler:

```
$ gcc -xc -E -v -
<…stripped…>
#include <...> search starts here:
<company specific path>/include
/usr/local/include
<company specific path>/include-fixed
/usr/include
End of search list.
```

I have also built gcc 5.4.0 with exactly the same build options. The search path looks like this for this version:

```
$ gcc -xc -E -v -
<…stripped…>
#include <...> search starts here:
<company specific path>/include
<company specific path>/include-fixed
/usr/local/include
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/include
End of search list.
```

Obviously the difference is /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu what is only present for 5.4.0. This is the dir where sys/cdefs.h resides.

Does anyone have any pointer what makes this difference? How could I build the 4.6.3 compiler to also have this path in the include search list?

I am of course aware of flags and env variables I can use to add this directory to the search path when using the compiler, but my goal would be to include this path in the compiler "hardcoded", so no additional -I and such flags should be used.

My gcc config options are:

```
configure --prefix=<company specific path>/gcc/4.6.3 --with-arch-32=i686
--with-sysroot=/ --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-system-zlib
--enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-multilib 
--enable-languages=c,c++,fortran 
--with-as=<company specific path>/gcc/4.6.3/bin/as 
--with-ld=<company specific path>/gcc/4.6.3/bin/ld 
--with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld
```

Comment: Add the path to the configure line : `CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu`

Comment: Unfortunately it does not seem to make any difference.

Comment: OK, I checked a couple of my Ubuntu installs : `/usr/include/sys/` is provided by a package  = `libc6-dev-i386` → provides (links) `/usr/include/{bits/, gnu/, sys/}`. The "forth" link = `/usr/include/asm/` is provided by `gcc-multilib` . Reason for the gcc 5.4.0 ← 4.6.3 difference could be because 4.6.3 was issued just before the final consistency of the new path´s ( usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu, etc. : Ubuntu 12.04 ... 17.10 have the final version of the new path´s.)